# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en MySQL que me muestre los registros que tienen un valor mayor al promedio de su grupo?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy aprendiendo SQL y ando practicando, y no he tenido problema, todo lo he podido resolver pero tengo mucho tiempo pensando en una consulta y no logro darle la vuelta.

La BBDD es la siguiente:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tienda;
CREATE DATABASE tienda CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE tienda;

CREATE TABLE fabricante (
  codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE producto (
  codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  precio DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  codigo_fabricante INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (codigo_fabricante) REFERENCES fabricante(codigo)
);

INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(1, 'Asus');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(2, 'Lenovo');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(3, 'Hewlett-Packard');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(4, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(5, 'Seagate');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(6, 'Crucial');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(7, 'Gigabyte');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(8, 'Huawei');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(9, 'Xiaomi');

INSERT INTO producto VALUES(1, 'Disco duro SATA3 1TB', 86.99, 5);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(2, 'Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB', 120, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(3, 'Disco SSD 1 TB', 150.99, 4);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(4, 'GeForce GTX 1050Ti', 185, 7);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(5, 'GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme', 755, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(6, 'Monitor 24 LED Full HD', 202, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(7, 'Monitor 27 LED Full HD', 245.99, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(8, 'Portátil Yoga 520', 559, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(9, 'Portátil Ideapd 320', 444, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(10, 'Impresora HP Deskjet 3720', 59.99, 3);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(11, 'Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw', 180, 3);
```

Y la consulta del ejercicio es la siguiente:

Devuelve un listado de todos los productos que tienen un precio mayor o igual a la media de todos los productos de su mismo fabricante.

Y este debe hacerse con una subconsulta.

Yo estoy intentando este codigo:

```
select fabricante.nombre, producto.nombre, precio, avg(precio) 
from fabricante 
join producto 
on codigo_fabricante=fabricante.codigo 
group by producto.codigo_fabricante 
having precio>=avg(precio)
```

Pero el resultado no es el que debería

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te sucede es que estás evitando hacer la subconsulta y te estás liando con los grupos. Vamos paso a paso:

Lo primero, vamos a obtener el precio medio de los productos de cada fabricante:

```
SELECT codigo_fabricante,
  AVG(precio) precio_medio
  FROM producto
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Después, vamos a combinar esta **subconsulta** con el resto de productos a través del código de cada fabricante:

```
SELECT * FROM producto
  JOIN (
    SELECT codigo_fabricante,
      AVG(precio) precio_medio
      FROM producto
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(codigo_fabricante);
```

Y, ya por último, nos quedamos con aquellos productos que cumplan la condición que nos piden:

```
SELECT * FROM producto
  JOIN (
    SELECT codigo_fabricante,
      AVG(precio) precio_medio
      FROM producto
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(codigo_fabricante)
  WHERE precio>=precio_medio;
```

Resultando esto:

```
+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+--------+--------------+
| codigo_fabricante | codigo | nombre                          | precio | precio_medio |
+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+--------+--------------+
|                 5 |      1 | Disco duro SATA3 1TB            |  86.99 |        86.99 |
|                 4 |      3 | Disco SSD 1 TB                  | 150.99 |       150.99 |
|                 7 |      4 | GeForce GTX 1050Ti              |    185 |          185 |
|                 6 |      5 | GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme         |    755 |        437.5 |
|                 1 |      7 | Monitor 27 LED Full HD          | 245.99 |      223.995 |
|                 2 |      8 | Portátil Yoga 520               |    559 |        501.5 |
|                 3 |     11 | Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw |    180 |      119.995 |
+-------------------+--------+---------------------------------+--------+--------------+
```

Fíjate que no han sido necesarios los nombres de los fabricantes en ningún momento, por lo que no ha habido que combinar con la tabla `fabricante`, así que ese `JOIN` te lo ahorras.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya vi el fallo.

Al no hacer la subconsulta no dividía las columnas precio y avg(precio) y la referencia entre las dos no funcionaba bien.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Estupendo. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)